# Vuforia apps & licensing

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

Before to write to Vuforia sales team I would like to know if there is someone who already purchased license with Vuforia.

In my mid-term projects I'll develop a few Unity/Vuforia apps to publish on Android/Apple stores. These apps will be freely downloadable but my customers (and customers of my customers) only can access to AR contents via cloud db.

These apps, in according with Vuforia agreement, are considered Internal Use or not? The right licence is Cloud or Custom?

Many thanks.

Comment: I appreciate your question but this is probably not the correct website. Have a look at about [which questions are on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I'm sorry, yes I read it but I can't find the right place. Please, do you can suggest another StackExchange website to post this argument?

Comment: What about [SoftwareRecommendation](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] guidelines. It's a question about a specific software product's license use, and should be addressed to the vendor or product team directly via their own web site. Posting off-topic questions here just because you don't know where else to ask them is not appropriate, especially when you know it's off topic here. Write to the sales team and ask them about their license use and pricing options.

Comment: Contact Vuforia support, they can brief you properly..

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 options if you want it for commercial purpose:

1. Starter - Access to the full Vuforia platform so you can build, demo
   and deploy your app at no charge with a watermark.
2. Classic - Unlimited device-based recognition for a single, flat fee
   per app.
3. Cloud - Cloud Recognition Service is for apps that use many targets
   or targets that need to be updated frequently.
   and if cloud is your first priority then it is bit costly.
   Read more :https://developer.vuforia.com/pricing

Answer (score 1):

**How Can You Add A License Key From Vuforia**

When you want to develop an AR project in Unity, you need to get a development key from Vuforia. Then, you need to add it to AR camera license key.

Firstly, you should log in to Vuforia Developer and click on Develop menu. (You can find the related image on the link.)
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u2vAzu1mlbPkxErF6yfyB53MyY7_gaal

Then, click on “Get Development Key”. Write your project name to remember later and check the box below which includes Vuforia Developer Agreement. Finally, click on “Confirm” and your key will be ready.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1asjBI-NffS-6u5-zE0lk63CrJz62ypT9

Then, open the key under License Manager menu bar, copy the key to paste on Unity.

In Unity, click on AR camera. If you cannot find license key part on your inspector, you should enable AR configuration. Click on Edit on the top, go to Project Settings and open Player part.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WViWm-AOombQKwr6Nt6BUvLIba56fxdL

You will find a box says “Vuforia Augmented Reality”. Check that box and you can continue to prepare your project.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pNwFA2p0MI55ZYSO45O2wVnd53z3-onq